# iOS - Storyboards - Link the same UITableViewController to 2 different UITabBarControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I'm working on a navigation style iOS app using Xcode 4.3.2, SDK v5.1 and storyboards.  The user can take several routes through the app but there is one particular table view scene that is used whichever route is taken.  I therefore just want to have this scene defined once, but be visible as a tab page in more than 1 different tab bar controllers.  The storyboard designer allows these relationships to be defined, but when the app is run the table view scene only appears as a tab button in the tab bar controller that it was most recently connected to.

Am I trying to achieve the impossible?  I would have thought if storyboard lets me connect everything up then it should be achievable.

Many thanks,
Jonathan